# How can my session update new changes every time my website is open?

Tags: php, database, html, session, phpmyadmin

**Description:**

In my website, there are cash amounts for every person with an account.

By the press of a button, a certain amount of money subtracts or adds from the cash amount.

**Problem:**

This change only shows in the database (phpmyadmin), but when I write the cash amount on my site, it still shows the old amount. The amount only updates when the user logs out and then back in. I want the amount to automatically update when the page is open.

**Question:**

Is there a line of code that i can add to my php at the top of the page after `session_start();` , such as `session_update();` *(I know this doesn't exist, it's just an example)* or something like that to check for the changes? Or will it have to be a complicated several lines of code? I want to do this without making the person log out.

Thanks for helping! (i'm kind of a noob at this :) )

Comment: There is no session_update() in php but you can set your session value $_SESSION['your_val']= $change_amount; And Please provide a code to know What you've done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a session variable of `$_SESSION['cash_amount']` and it currently equal $100. If $10 gets subtracted, then in your code, you just say `$_SESSION['cash_amount'] -= 10;` and it will subtract that from the session variable so next time the user sees the page, it will have the correct amount. Of course you're probably pulling this from the database and if that's the case, then you want that session variable to be equal to the result of the query you're pulling from.

And if you want to do this without refreshing the page, then you'll use AJAX and pull the amount in that way but that's a whole different ball of wax that you might not be prepared for yet.

Comment: I'll try it out, and i already used ajax to pull the amount. Thanks though.